# web scraping a table with R

Tags: r, json, web-scraping

i am trying to web scrape a table from pitch book web site . 
 But using simple HTML does not work because pitch book uses java script  instead of  HTML  to load the data so  i need  execute the JS in order to extract the info  from the  json file . 
this is my code :

```
    library(httr)
    library(jsonlite)
    library(magrittr)  
    json=get("https://my.pitchbook.com/old/ 
    homeContent.64ea0536fd321cc1dd3b.js") %>% 
    content(as='text') %>% 
    fromJSON()
```

i get this error :

```
    Error in 
   get("https://my.pitchbook.com/old/homeContent.64ea0536fd321cc1dd3b.js") 
    : 
     object 
  'https://my.pitchbook.com/old/homeContent.64ea0536fd321cc1dd3b.js'
   not found
```

what ever data i am trying to load it returns the same error . 
would appreciate your help :) 
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called `base::get` and not `httr::GET`.
So it should be

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)  
json <- GET(
  "https://my.pitchbook.com/old/homeContent.64ea0536fd321cc1dd3b.js"
) %>% 
  content("text") %>% 
  fromJSON()
```

but I'm not entirely sure that your website url gives a valid json. This in itself will give

> lexical error: invalid char in json text.